# Why the certificate Authority always failed the temporary challenge file created by Certbot?

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

i'm using jonasal/nginx-certbot image for letsencript certificates generate.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: jonasal/nginx-certbot:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - CERTBOT_EMAIL=your@email.org
    env_file:
      - ./nginx-certbot.env
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - nginx_secrets:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./user_conf.d:/etc/nginx/user_conf.d

volumes:
  nginx_secrets:
```

nginx-certbot.env:

```
# Required
CERTBOT_EMAIL=your@email.org

# Optional (Defaults)
STAGING=0
DHPARAM_SIZE=2048
RSA_KEY_SIZE=2048
ELLIPTIC_CURVE=secp256r1
USE_ECDSA=0
RENEWAL_INTERVAL=8d

# Advanced (Defaults)
DEBUG=0
USE_LOCAL_CA=0
```

example_server.conf:

```
server {
    # Listen to port 443 on both IPv4 and IPv6.
    listen 443 ssl default_server reuseport;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server reuseport;

    # Domain names this server should respond to.
    server_name autocensor.ru www.autocensor.ru;

    # Load the certificate files.
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/autocensor.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/autocensor.ru/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/autocensor.ru/chain.pem;

    # Load the Diffie-Hellman parameter.
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/dhparams/dhparam.pem;

    return 200 'Let\'s Encrypt certificate successfully installed!';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
}
```

and on docker-compose up running i get this error:

> Requesting a certificate for autocensor.ru and [www.autocensor.ru](http://www.autocensor.ru) nginx_1
> |  nginx_1  | Certbot failed to authenticate some domains
> (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these
> problems: nginx_1  |   Domain: autocensor.ru nginx_1  |   Type:
> unauthorized nginx_1  |   Detail: The key authorization file from the
> server did not match this challenge
> "pp6XaPNCuZawYdO3O7FNKHfeWtpf1bQzcoIyXVGNOzM.kTA13USq2rwk6zJAuXHkRl6UF3hcK_tiHGRBYu100gU"
> != "pp6XaPNCuZawYdO3O7FNKHfeWtpf1bQzcoIyXVGNOzM"

however https://autocensor.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/pp6XaPNCuZawYdO3O7FNKHfeWtpf1bQzcoIyXVGNOzM.kTA13USq2rwk6zJAuXHkRl6UF3hcK_tiHGRBYu100gU shows the full hash code and it does not seem that certbot cut it off for some reason.

i tried to do that using original phusion/baseimage image. The result is the same. What i'm doing wrong?

May be i have to output only the part of the hash? I tried to print out other content and it showed me smth like this:

> "pp6XaPNCuZawYdO3O7FNKHfeWtpf1bQzcoIyXVGNOzM.kTA13USq2rwk6zJAuXHkRl6UF3hcK_tiHGRBYu100gU"
> != "content"

it means that the output content stays from the right side.

I am grateful for any hint!

Comment: Do you have any firewalling in place, either on the machine or somewhere on the network path?

Comment: no, nothig, it's just vps server with docker on board. simple nginx configuration with no plugin

Comment: What does `nginx -T` say? Do you see the LE request in your logs?